# Android: Time and Timezone problems

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar

I get time data about some event from server in UTC. For example, it should happen in 5 hours.

But when user change time of the device (+2 hours, for example), time before an event becomes 3 hours (not 5)

But if user changes not time but time zone, then everything works ok.
Then I decided to check timezone offset. Even if I change my time to +2 hours, system still thinks I'm on my timezone's time.

I have the same timezone offset before and after time change.

Then how to deal with this?

I want if user changes time +2 hours, then to still to show these 5 hours before an event, not 3.

I use `Calendar.getInstance().time.time` for checking my time.

And it happens that system time is 15:00, event will be on 20:00, user changes time to 19:00 and the app shows that event will be in an hour.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to use system time. Is it possible to get the timezone of the user rather than the time set on the device. Otherwise, I would recommend that your system relies on 1 universal timezone and you convert to that before.making calculations. Get the time from that timezone rather than the users set time or the users time zone at the point of initiation.

Answer (score 2):

If you getting the time in UTC then you can compare it with a UTC time (which doesn't go backwards and forwards of course). Using `java.time` things are easier.

For example:

```
 Instant fromServer = serverTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
 Instant now = Instant.now();
 long diff = now.until(fromServer, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
```